# Are "out" parameters a bad thing in .NET?

Tags: .net

Are "out" parameters a bad thing in .NET? Any good articles/discussions on this topic?

Comment: This question has a good discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214688/why-does-the-net-framework-guidelines-recommend-that-you-dont-use-refout-argume

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, I have [an article on what ref/out do](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) - but it doesn't discuss whether or not you should use them.

Basically `out` parameters are usually a sign that you want to effectively return two results from a method. That's *usually* a code smell - but there are some cases (most notably with the TryXXX pattern) where you genuinely want to return two pieces of information for good reasons and it doesn't make much sense to encapsulate them together.

In other words, avoid out/ref where you can do so easily, but don't go massively out of your way to avoid them.

Answer (score 6):

For most circumstances I would recommend against using Out parameters. They basically add side-effects to your code and could be a nightmare when it comes to debugging.

There's an article on MSDN regarding Out parameters available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of tuples, they're sometimes the cleanest way to do things.  I generally hate them, though.

F# has some nice syntactical sugar for dealing with them.  Rather than making me deal with `out` parameters, it treats them as methods that return tuples instead.  The various `TryParse` methods end up returning two element tuples:

```
let success, value = Int32.TryParse("1234")
(* success is true *)
(* value is 1234 *)
```

It's quite handy, and doesn't make me feel dirty.

Comment: For this particular case, you can use Nullable<int> pretty easily, with a wrapper method which returns null for "parse failed". It's not quite as neat as the F# solution, but worth bearing in mind if you're using C# and don't want an out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are really useful when needed.

An [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336814.aspx) article for both ref and out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  My answer is that I don't particularly like them, but I do use them in one of my projects where multiple return values are common.  I have a financial data library that returns the actual price (or null/zero), a major error code, and a minor error code.  The library has dozens to hundreds of methods, and each error code is a different type, so creating custom classes for each one and returning an instance of that would be very unwieldy.

Answer (score -1):

FxCop doesn't think it's a good idea...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182146(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Out parameters are useful when you need to return more than one object as a result of a function.  To my eyes,

```
void doSomeThing(Thing toDoItTo,
                 out OtherThing result1,
                 out AnotherThing result2)
{
    ...
}

OtherThing y;
AnotherThing z;

doSomeThing(x, out y, out z);

y.method1();
z.method2();
```

is a lot cleaner than

```
struct DoSomeThingResults
{
    public OtherThing Result1;
    public OtherThing Result2;
}

DoSomeThingResults doSomeThing(Thing toDoItTo)
{
    ...
}

DoSomethingResults results = doSomeThing(x);

results.Result1.method1();
results.Result2.method2();
```

and additionally, using out parameters means that the results are guaranteed to be assigned.

Answer (score -2):

it is not at all bad to use the Out

let's try precising the benefits :

```
 using ref force us to initialize it so we are letting the ref variable to place in heap and consume some spaces .

 in most cases we return null if the operation has some none logic conditions 

 but with Out we avoid consuming the heap and refspace
```