# how to return 2 values from 1 c# methods?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I return multiple values from a function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

C# methods is always like this:

```
public <return type> funName()
{
//do sth
return someValueformatedasReturnType;
}
```

how to return 2 values from 1 c# methods?
This is a interview question, as many as you know. Thanks!

Comment: So what was your answer?

Comment: i answer out/ref  class/struct,I just feel it maybe have more ways to reach it(and I got 'Tuple' here).so I ask question here ,I dont know why so many votedown on this subject,,,,,,,,,,,diu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From best to worst (IMHO):

- Create a new class for the return type
- Use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)
- Use [out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Comment: Why is a `Tuple` better than out parameters?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett That's subjective, but out parameters always add a lot of boilerplate to the caller (needs to declare the variables beforehand) and complicate the method signature (some return types are on the left hand side, some others are in the signature). Of course, it depends, e.g. `int.TryParse` makes sense as an out parameter rather than a `Tuple<bool,int>` or even `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: @George - I can't speak for Michael, but  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281036/are-out-parameters-a-bad-thing-in-net this question and the first response summarizes my sentiments on out parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options:

1. output parameters
2. Tuple
3. Class that has 2 properties

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ref or out keyword for your function parameters.

```
int i;
int j;

dosomething(out i, out j);    

public void dosomething(out int a, out int b)
{
   a = 1;
   b = 2;
}
```

after calling the function, i = 1, j = 2. same for ref keyword, msdn tells the difference :)

or return a tuple.

*@tudor*

look at your names, using out as object name :S, out is used to pass value by reference!

Answer (score 0):

Define a new data type (Class) with the two outputs:

```
public class Output
{
    public object Val1 { get; set; }
    public object Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

and return a new object of type Output:

```
public Output FunName()
{
     Output out = new Output;
     out.Val1 = val1;
     out.Val2 = val2;
     return out;
}
```