# return multiple values in static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, return

How do I return FirstName and Surname in the following class?

```
public static string GetAccount(int AccountId)
{        
    LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

    var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
             where p.AccountId == AccountId
             select new { Name = p.FirstName, Surname = p.Surname }).Single();

    return ??;
}
```

Comment: assuming you want the return type correct as well and you don't just want `return string.Format("{0} {1}",q.Name,q.Surname);`

Answer (score 6):

You can return a strongly typed class, dynamic object or a tuple.
I prefer to return a strongly typed class.

The problem using the `dynamic` type is that you dont get 
intellisense and exceptions only at runtime.

The problem with a tuple is that it does not show you what
you return. You or other developers have to read the method
to know whats the Name and whats the Surname.

#### Sample

```
public class MyResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public static MyResult GetAccount(int AccountId)
{        
    LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

    var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
             where p.AccountId == AccountId
             select new MyResult{ Name = p.FirstName, Surname = p.Surname }).Single();

    return q;
}
```

### Update

I suggest to use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single`. This will make sure you 
get a `null` result if the Account does not exist instead of throw a exception.

```
//
select new MyResult{ Name = p.FirstName, Surname = p.Surname }).SingleOrDefault();
//
```

Comment: This code assumes one and only one item is returned from the query. `Single` throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the collection.

Comment: That worked! My goal is to get the data from the account table and fill textboxes in the webpage with the details: name, surname, address, etc.. I get the data ike this:

FirstNameTextBox.Text = MyResults.GetAccount(AccountId).FirstName;
SurnameTextBox.Text = MyResults.GetAccount(AccountId).Surname;
AddressTextBox.Text = MyResults.GetAccount(AccountId).Address;
.
.
.
and so on...

Is that the most effective way of using the class? It seems like I have to call a class everytime I fill one of the textboxes... is there a better alternative?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to define a new object for your return type, you can use `Tuple<string, string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in two objects by reference and you can just set them.

Altered to make it a try function as an example of a less code smell version

```
public static bool TryGetAccount(int AccountId, out String FirstName, out String Surname)
{        
    LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

    var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
             where p.AccountId == AccountId
             select new { Name = p.FirstName, Surname = p.Surname }).SingleOrDefault();


    FirstName=(q==null) ? null: q.Name;
    Surname=(q==null) ? null: q.Surname;
    return q!=null;
}
```

Now you can do

```
string firstName;
string surname;

if (TryGetAccount(id, out firstName,out surname)) {
  // firstName now equals the first name and surname now equals the surname
} else {
  // Deal with value not found
```

}

Comment: @the_joric Bit of a sweeping statement with no explanation, you've got me all worried now.

Comment: out parameters are not by definition bad, many coders consider them code smell as they result in side effects.  However they do have their uses - especially in the Try style of functions. [See SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281036/are-out-parameters-a-bad-thing-in-net)

Comment: @BobVale Curious, how can they result in side effects? The compiler stops use of `out` parameters before assignment, and the caller explicitly has to specify `out` so they know whatever variable they provide will be changed. Side-effects tend to be unwanted state changes.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth They are considered side effects because each variable is actually passed into the function as a reference to the same memory location, the value could be altered after the function returns if the function starts an async process.

Comment: @BobVale thanks, I'll have to keep that in mind. I've seen them drifting around the current codebase I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another (not the best :) ) option is to return an array:

```
public static string[] GetAccount(int AccountId)
{        
    LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

    var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
             where p.AccountId == AccountId
             select new { Name = p.FirstName, Surname = p.Surname }).Single();

    return new []{q.Name, q.Surname};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net 4 you could return a dynamic instead of a string and grab both values directly from the returned object.

Comment: Only within the same assembly, or if you're using InternalsVisibleToAttribute. Anonymous types are implicitly "internal", which causes issues for `dynamic`.

Comment: This will have the overhead of involving the DLR for what can be achieved with either a new class or a `Tuple<string, string>`. Plus you lose IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

How about returning it as [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) as long as you dont mind using the retunred type this way tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hashtable to evade creating the new result-class.
Something like this:

```
  public static Hashtable GetAccount(int AccountId)
    {        
       LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

         var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
         where p.AccountId == AccountId
         select new { Name = p.FirstName, Surname = p.Surname }).Single();

        return new Hashtable(q.FirstName, q.Surname);
    }
```

Than you can get the Surname by your FirstName as key.

Comment: But then you could just as easily return a `new DictionaryEntry<string,string>(q.FirstName,q.Surname)` which has the benefit of stronger typing, but a Tuple<string,string> is even better.